# vb.net exclude specific file names from copying?

Tags: .net, vb.net

How to exclude specific file being copied during copy process. I want to exclude from being copied for example name.xml, adress.xml and data.xml

Here is the code from MSDN I use:

```
    Dim BackupDir As String = Application.StartupPath & "\backup"
    Dim sourceDir As String = Application.StartupPath

    If Not Directory.Exists(BackupDir) Then
        IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(BackupDir)
    End If

    Try
        Dim xmlList As String() = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.xml")

        For Each f As String In xmlList
            'Remove path from the file name.
            Dim fName As String = f.Substring(sourceDir.Length + 1)
            File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, fName), Path.Combine(BackupDir, fName), True)
        Next
    Catch copyError As IOException
        Console.WriteLine(copyError.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare a List(Of String) with the names of the files that you don't want to copy, then use `Path.GetFileName` to extract the filename from the full file names returned by the Directory.GetFiles().
Before executing the copy check if the file is contained in the list of `excludedFiles`

```
   Dim excludeFiles = new List(Of String)()
   excludedFiles.Add("file1.xml")
   excludedFiles.Add("file2.xml")
   excludedFiles.Add("file3.xml")


   For Each f As String In xmlList
        'Remove path from the file name.
        Dim fName As String = Path.GetFileName(f)
            if excludedFiles.IndexOf("file3.xml", _
               StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) <> -1 Then
            File.Copy(f, Path.Combine(BackupDir, fName), True)
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: steve works like a charm, thanks. Just added d letter into first excludeFiles and c into second one :)

Comment: Changed the method Contains in IndexOf. This allows to pass an enum to avoid problems with filename case (I.E. FILE1.xml)